# JS Object && Function. Кто может пояснить мой пример?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, prototype, прототипное-наследование

В консоли выполнил две команды на понимание кто кому прототип и получил дважды true. Хочу понимать в чем кроется секрет и кто кому из них прототип (предок) в JS

```
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object)
//true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function)
//true
```

Comment: Как я думаю Function наследник Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что `Object` и `Function` - это две функции (т.н. функции-конструкторы). А у любой функции в цепочке прототипов есть как `Function.prototype`, так и `Object.prototype`, ведь любая функция является объектом.

Если вы хотите проверить кто чей прототип - нужно с прототипами и работать:

```
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) // false
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) // true
```

В целом же цепочка прототипов выглядит вот так (протитипы внизу, производные от них объекты - вверху):

```
 Function  Object
       \   /
        \ / 
         |
Function.prototype
         |
         |
 Object.prototype
```